# How to ensure less UDP packets are dropped?

Tags: python, linux, udp

I am recording data via UDP on Linux in Python. Everything seems to work and I dont lose any packets. After some period of time I will drop one packet and then it starts dropping many more packets. I understand UDP is lossy but is there anythingI can do that may help?

Answer (score 0):

This command will increase the buffer for reading in data:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=2097152
```

It worked for me